# TextMate alternative for Linux

Tags: linux, editor, textmate

Is there any TextMate alternative for Linux?

Something like [e-TextEditor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) for Windows

Comment: Which features do you mean? The text editing interface? The pluggability? The syntax highlighting? Just everything?

Comment: a good topic got cloded by SO gods again..

Comment: hey SO, stop closing topics left and right... or at least allow a way to re-open closed topics...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, the [gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/) text editor. The are some must read articles on this subject on the web:

- [Pimp my Gedit (Was: Textmate for Linux)](http://grigio.org/pimp_my_gedit_was_textmate_linux)

Comment: Is the first link safe? I get a `Malware Detected` warning form google chrome.

Comment: articles are depricated, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387432/how-to-make-gedit-look-like-textmate

Answer (score 40):

Check out sublime: http://www.sublimetext.com/. It's not quite textmate but it has some pretty awesome features.

Comment: I am a big fan of Sublime Text. They are currently working on version 2, but you can download the alpha and use it for free.

Comment: Yes sublime text seems to be much better than pimping GEdit.

Comment: Worth mentioning that unlike TextMate, Sublime is not open-source.

Answer (score 23):

Why not Vim? It most likely comes by default with your distribution and is a lot more powerful than TextMate. I recommend it, even on Mac OS X.

Or Emacs.

---

**Edit**

I keep seeing this answer upvoted from time to time so, FWIW, this is the story of my switch from TextMate to Vim:

As a long-time BBEdit user, I fell in love with TextMate's elegance and intuitiveness in 2006 and became proficient with it quite quickly. A couple of years later, though, I switched to Linux at home and went on a 10 months-long editor safari, looking for a cross-platform alternative to TextMate.

In those 10 months I tried seriously *every* editor, lightweight IDE or full-blown IDE that worked both on Linux and on Mac OS X with varying success. Too bloated, too light on features, not well integrated in the OS… every editor/IDE I tried had unacceptable flaws.

Last on the list were Emacs and Vim, mostly because of their legendary learning curves and their perceived "strangeness". Both editors passed all my tests successfully but Vim ultimately won because of the intuitiveness of its language and the simplicity of its configuration.

So… I then spent a few months doing the most pointless thing ever: trying to turn Vim into a TextMate clone. I somehow pulled this off but the result was slow and bloated and all duct-tapped to death. Frustration led me to enlightenment and made "get" Vim which I've been using with much pleasure as my main editor for the last 4+ years.

Comment: Its mostly imaginary learning curve can be daunting, though.

Comment: Not that I'm sad or angry or whatever… but why the downvote? Disagreement? Concerns about the editorial quality of this answer?

Answer (score 4):

There is also [Redcar Editor](http://redcareditor.com/):

- textmate wannabe clone
- runs on Java (crossplatform)
- written and extendable in Ruby (JRuby)
- open source
- plugins
- extend-it-yourself feature
- alpha (hurry and contribute)

Comment: It seems awesome, but I can't get it to work. =(

Comment: Redcar is way too heavyweight for a text editor.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use the [gmate](http://blog.siverti.com.br/gmate/) extension to gedit. However, it is also possible to compile E on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [scribes](http://scribes.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

Since the people behind E released the source, there's a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/etexteditor/e/) you can clone and install on your own.

[Read more!](http://e-texteditor.com/blog/2009/linux-progress)