# How to make Gedit look like Textmate?

Tags: ubuntu, textmate, gedit

I want to make Gedit look like Textmate, and act like it too. I have read many tutorials on the net, but can't find an easy to follow guide. I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and would like to use it for Ruby on Rails and other web languages. I want only the core functions such as class/project browser and syntax highlighting. Can someone provide an easy to follow guide or point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-on-rails/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gedit-gmate
```

that should work

Comment: I have installed it, how do I actually use it?

Comment: go to plugin menu and verify all those plugs are activated, for details how to use each plugin/hotkeys you have to check the plugin documentation